# passing the urls from one file to another in django python

Tags: python, django

I tried to pass the url link from project ulrs to application urls but getting an error in Django.

> Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /hello/all
>
> Exception Value: The included urlconf 'article.urls' does not appear to have  any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue probably caused by a circular import.

the code in application  article\urls.py

```
article_url_pattern= [
     url(r'^all/$', 'article.views.hello')
]
```

the code in project TestApplication\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^hello/", include('article.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rename the `article_url_pattern` variable to `urlpatterns` in `article\urls.py`. Django looks for that variable in any urlconf file, and will not recognise any others.